# Diagnose input/output errors on a Truecrypt container

Tags: io, truecrypt

I have been trying to get a local repository located on a usb drive working on an air-gapped machine. The repository was created with apt-mirror on the same kind of system (ubuntu i386).

Currently I am blocked by being unable to scan the packages on the usb drive. This is what happens:

```
cd /media/truecrypt1/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com
sudo dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
bash: Packages.gz Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: error reading archive magic version number from file ./ubuntu/pool/main/libm/libmaa/libmaa-dev_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb: Input/Output error
dpkg-scanpackages: error: couldn't parse control information from ./ubuntu/pool/main/libm/libmaa/libmaa-dev_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb
```

What could be my problem here? How do I diagnose an input/output error on a TrueCrypt container?

Comment: Does your script have write access to the USB hard drive?

Comment: It's not a script, there are only two commands in the quote, cd and sudo dpkg-scanpackages.

Comment: if your mirror was created with `apt-mirror`, why do you even need to run `dpkg-scanpackages`?  `apt-mirror` will have mirrored the Packages file along with the `.deb` files.  As i mentioned for your previous question, you just need to specify the correct path in the `deb` line in your `sources.list`.  If the one i suggested doesn't work, then examine your mirror directory tree and try another....eventually trial and error will get you the correct path.

Comment: @cas There are four directories with Packages.gz files corresponding to main/restricted/universe/multiverse. One thing that concerns me is that all of them have a parent "binary-amd64". Does that mean they are all amd64 binaries? I don't understand this because the machine I built the repository on is i386. Why would it be creating an amd64 repository?

Comment: perhaps because you either told `apt-mirror` to mirror only the `amd64` arch, or `apt-mirror` defaults to doing that (there's a `defaultarch` config option in `mirror.list` which defaults to the host's arch)?  what does `grep amd64 /etc/apt/mirror.list` show?

Comment: and, yes, you have created an amd64-only mirror.  if it had mirrored i386 as well, you'd also have `binary-i386` directories with `Packages` files.

Comment: @cas hmm, that sucks because now I am going to have to download the whole thing again which takes like 16 hours; there is no mention of amd64 in my mirror list I am going to post a separate question.

Comment: yes, it sucks....but should take a bit less than 16 hours because you don't need to re-mirror the architecture:all packages (or source packages if you mirrored them).  I'd suggest explicitly using `deb-i386` lines in your `mirror.list` file.   BTW, where did you mirror it from?  an official ubuntu mirror or from somewhere else that might only have amd64 and all packages?

Comment: @cas I posted my mirror.list to a separate question (archive.ubuntu.com). I think what was in this this file was whatever apt-mirror created by default because I do not remember modifying it.

Comment: “Input/output error” has nothing to do with the program that's accessing the disk. Most likely, your USB drive is damaged. It could also be a driver bug. To start with, does `cat /path/to/truecrypt-volume.tc >/dev/null` succeed?